# Object size discrepancy

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out why certain arrays I am saving as .rda's seem to eat up more memory than others of equal size. Below are two objects, x and y,of the same size, type, and dimension.  When I save each of these, one is 41 Mb and the other is 6Mb.  Can anyone think of a reason why this could happen?

```
> dim(x)
[1]    71    14 10000
> dim(y)
[1]    71    14 10000 
> class(x)
[1] "array"
> class(y)
[1] "array"  
> object.size(y)
79520208 bytes
> object.size(x)
79520208 bytes
```

Comment: what say `str(x)` and `str(y)` ?

Comment: Or better yet, what commands did you use to generate x and y?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you save using either the `save` or `saveRDS` commands, the default is to use compression. If you have different content in the vectors, they'll compress differently...

Try `save` with `compress=FALSE` and compare again...

In the example below there is almost a 700x difference in file size:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(1e6)  # random values should not compress well...
y <- rep(0, 1e6) # zeroes should compress very well...
object.size(x) # 8000040 bytes
object.size(y) # 8000040 bytes

save('x', file='x.rds')
save('y', file='y.rds')
file.info(c('x.rds', 'y.rds'))$size
#[1] 5316773    7838

save('x', file='x.rds', compress=FALSE)
save('y', file='y.rds', compress=FALSE)
file.info(c('x.rds', 'y.rds'))$size
#[1] 8000048 8000048
```

Comment: In case it's relevant for others: `readr::write_rds()` does NOT compress by default - it is not interchangeable with `saveRDS()`.

Answer (score 7):

They both could be arrays of characters, or lists or dataframes. Or one could be character (one or two byte would be the minumum element size and the otehr could be numeric (8 bytes per element) or the biggerone could have large character elements ..... or  a variety of other possibilities. I get somewhat the same results as you with:

```
x <- array(runif( 71* 14 *10000), dim = c(71 ,   14, 10000) )
 save(x, file="test.rda")
 object.size(x)
# 79520208 bytes  and the file is over 50 MB
x <- array(sample(letters, 71* 14 *10000, replace=TRUE), dim = c(71 ,   14, 10000) )
 save(x, file="test2.rda")
 object.size(x)
# 79521456 bytes   and the file is around 8 MB
```

Comment: I couldn't find a link on my first attempt, but I have a sneaking suspicion that this must have come up at least a few times on r-help.

Comment: hmmm. They are both numeric. In the 41Mb array I am storing values that are logged (x) , could that have something to do with it?

Comment: I posted another interesting observation.