# R-shiny. Serialization size probem

Tags: r, serialization, shiny

I have this app:

```
library(shiny)
library(gbm)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("test","Serialize Object")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$test,{
    mdl<-gbm(data=iris,formula=Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Length+Petal.Width,distribution="gaussian")
    srl<-serialize(mdl, NULL)
    print(object.size(srl))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

when I click on the button, it prints the size of the serialized object model:

```
3512568 bytes
```

However, if I execute the same in a R script:

```
mdl<-gbm(data=iris, formula=Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, distribution="gaussian")
srl<-serialize(mdl, NULL)
print(object.size(srl))
```

.. it prints:

```
42080 bytes
```

Why such difference?. I want serialized the model in a Shiny application because I want to store it in a database. But 3.5 mb is quite big for my purposes.
Does anyone knows the reason for that difference of size?
Thanks.

Comment: It's probably because of attached environments. With some other models you could probably use  [`butcher::axe_env()`](https://butcher.tidymodels.org/reference/axe_env.html) , but gbm isn't supported. Might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230920/saverds-inflating-size-of-object , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144239/how-to-use-saverds-refhook-parameter